# What is the correct response format of a 406 HTTP status error

Tags: http, http-headers

I want to issue a 406 Not Acceptable error in my application and I want to alert the client about the available alternative formats.

From the [HTTP protocol spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.7):

> Unless it was a HEAD request, the response SHOULD include an entity
>   containing a list of available entity characteristics and location(s)
>   from which the user or user agent can choose the one most appropriate.
>   The entity format is specified by the media type given in the
>   Content-Type header field. Depending upon the format and the
>   capabilities of the user agent, selection of the most appropriate
>   choice MAY be performed automatically. However, this specification
>   does not define any standard for such automatic selection.

Do I add that entity in the response body?
What's the format of that list?

Comment: @CodeCaster, what do you mean? It seems that such format is not defined.

Comment: @Opal my point exactly. You'll have to make one up, and implement it in both server and client.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. However some general format should be standarized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing in the spec is:

> The entity format is specified by the media type given in the Content-Type header field

This page is quite useful:
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/apc.html#_proactive_negotiation

As-is the article it references:
http://bit.ly/agent-conneg

The examples there describe negotiation, in situations where you would return a 300 Multiple Choices response, a situation similar to how you might provide alternatives in a 406 Not Acceptable response.  It follows the same ideas where you provide an entity in the format of the returning content type - if you are returning text, write some text; if you are returning HTML, write some HTML.

```
HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/xhtml
Content-Length:XXX

<p>
  Select one:
</p>
<a href="/results/fr" hreflang="fr">French</a>
<a href="/results/en-US" hreflang="en-US">US English</a>
<a href="/results/de" hreflang="de">German</a>
```

A standard format would indeed be useful for automatic renegotiation, but the spec stays away from defining that.  I would agree with the writer that the best way to inform of alternatives to a 406 is to use the same "Link" headers in the example from the oreilly.com page, as they describe:

> An alternative approach is to use Link headers. This has the advantage of being a standard header that any client can understand. Here is an example:

```
HTTP/1.1 300 Multiple Choices
Host: www.example.org
Content-Length: 0
Link: <http://www.example.org/results/png>; type="image/png",
      <http://www.example.org/results/jpeg>;type="image/jpeg",
      <http://www.example.org/results/gif>;type="image/gif"
```

However, don't expect guaranteed results on every client with something that is not standardized.